# how to count the number 0to9 based on the number of digits in javascript

Tags: javascript, countdown, digits

i am trying to implement number of digits for ex: if i give digit=3 in url, my output is 000 digit =5, my output is 00000 likewise it is coming but i need each and every digit should count 0 to 9 based on the digit value. for ex: if i give digit=3,it will come 000 and i need those three zero to count 0to9,0to9,0to9. i hope you all understand my question please help me this os for creating number of digit code but i need count code
this is my html code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <style>
      div{
        display:inline-block;
      } 
    </style>
    <script>...</script> 
  </head>
  <body>   
     <div id="output" class="out"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is js code

```
window.onload=function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var i=1;    
    var param = getParameterByName("digit"); 
    var val="";
    while(i<=param)
    {

        if(!document.getElementById('timedrpact'+i))
        {
            var ele = document.createElement("div");
            ele.setAttribute("id","timedrpact"+i);
            ele.setAttribute("class","inner"); 
            ele.innerHTML="0";

            output.appendChild(ele);            
        }
        i++;
    }
};

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: can you indent that HTML and JS properly please?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i put separately html and js code now you can see and please tell me any solution

Comment: HTML note: you're using an obsolete HTML syntax - HTML5 starts with `<!doctype html>` and uses `<meta charset="utf-8">` to indicate utf8 unicode content. Also don't regexp your way through `location.search`; the spec is extremely rigid so you can just do something like `window.location.search.replace('?','').split("&")` and then run the result through a map function.

Comment: actual code comment: your question talks about `digit=5`, your code search for `digi`, not `digit`.

Comment: @oh ok no problem i will change digit instead of digi. how to count those numbers from 0 to 9

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Once check it. Is this is what your requirement. If not let me know it. I do my best.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9ZBZuHsfkvOGjWPNq0ao?p=preview

HTML Code:

```
<body>
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="startCount()">Start Count</button>

<div id="output"></div>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: @RRajeshwar ok i already i got solution for that, but my problem is i need to get milliseconds as a random for ex: var countdownTimer = setInterval('generate()', 1000); here we will give 1000 milliseconds instead of this i have to give random which means automatically it will take some random milliseconds 100 milliseconds for one number and it will 150 milliseconds for another number so let me know if you know